# Array Handling with c program

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to find best 3 value from an array where i got array from input.how many element will be in the array will also input from user. then randomly array will input. 
but how can i find best three element from this array.
**array = (12, 20, 15, 28, 35)**. i want to **find 35 28 20**. what is the way. want some example of code.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? And what have you already tried?

Comment: best means biggest in value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Begin
    Create storage for three elements of the array
    Load the storage area with the first three elements of the array
    Iterate through the array, starting with the fourth element:
        If the current element in the array is larger than any of the three elements in the storage:
            Replace the smallest of the three elements with that element
        End
    End
End
```